# React Router DOM is rendering 2 components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

This is my router structure:

```
<Router>
      <main className="py-3">
        <Switch>
          <Container>
            <Route exact path="/admin" component={AdminScreen}></Route>

            <Route path="/:campaignId" component={CampaignScreen}></Route>
            <Route path="/" component={HomeScreen} exact></Route>
          </Container>
        </Switch>
      </main>
    </Router>
```

For "some" reason, when I go to `/admin` i also get the `CampaignScreen` rendered.

I added the `<Switch>` as you can see, but it does not seem to help.
Where lies the problem?

Comment: *admin* is a potential *campaignId*. The quickest alternative solution is to change the route to something like: **/_something_/:campaignId**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `admin` can theoretically also be a `campaignId` react router thinks it matches both routes, and you have the `<Container>` element directly inside the `Switch` it still renders both, the solution is to have your routes directly in the `Switch`

Comment: שכוייח . Is there a difference if I put the HomeScreen route at the top?

Comment: @Mendi Sterenfeld with `exact` on the `HomeScreen` route it should work with the `HomeScreen` route on top.

Comment: However you still ned the `Switch` to prevent the `/:campaignId` route to render when on the `/admin` route.